# SQL SERVER - Complicated SQL query 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables **document** and **documentd** the first one contains the numbers of the documents '**doc_num**' primary key, document types '*doc_type*' (FACA, BLCO, BLCM, BLCK .....) and the document date '**doc_date**'

**MANY DOCUMENTS DIFFERENT DATES AND DIFFERENT TYPES**

Table **DOCUMENT**:

```
|    DOC_NUM       | DOC_TYPE |   DOC_DATE  |
|                  |          |             |
|  ACHAT190122001  |   FACA   |  22/01/2019 |  
|  ACHAT190222001  |   FACA   |  22/02/2019 |
|  ACHAT190322001  |   FACA   |  22/03/2019 |
|  BLCO190122001   |   BLCO   |  22/01/2019 |
|  BLCO190123001   |   BLCO   |  23/01/2019 |
|  BLCM190122001   |   BLCM   |  22/01/2019 |
|  ACHAT190102010  |   FACA   |  02/01/2019 |
|  ACHAT190103011  |   FACA   |  03/01/2019 |
|  ACHAT190422005  |   FACA   |  22/04/2019 |
```

[DOCUMENT TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ualav.png)

The second table contains as foreign key '**doc_num**' the articles of each document '**art_code**' and finally the prices of the articles '**art_prix**'.

**DETAILS OF EACH DOCUMENTS IN DOCUMENT TABLE WITH DIFFERENT AND SAME ARTICLES AND PRICES.**

Table **DOCUMENTD**:

```
|     DOC_NUM      |  ART_CODE |ART_PRIX |
|                  |           |         |
|  ACHAT190122001  |  ARTICLE1 |  1000   |
|  ACHAT190122001  |  ARTICLE2 |  2000   |
|  ACHAT190102010  |  ARTICLE1 |   950   |
|  ACHAT190103011  |  ARTICLE1 |   980   |
|  ACHAT190422005  |  ARTICLE2 |  1200   |
|  ACHAT190120006  |  ARTICLE2 |  1000   |
|  BLCO190122001   |  ARTICLE1 |   900   |
|  BLCO190123001   |  ARTICLE2 |   800   |
```

[DOCUMENTD TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGKoO.png)

My goal is to join the two tables using '**doc_num**' selects all **BLC** type documents and their articles **except the prices they must be THE LAST UPDATED PRICE IN FCAC TYPE FOR EXAMPLE**

**RESULT:**

```
| BLCO190122001 |  ARTICLE1 | 1000 |  22/01/2019 |
| BLCO190123001 |  ARTICLE2 | 1200 |  22/04/2019 |
```

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItpzE.png)

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: select * from document inner join documentd on document.doc_num = documentd.doc_num where document.doc_type = 'BLCO'

Comment: select a.doc_type b.doc_type,  a.doc_num, a.doc_date  from document a inner join documentd d on a.doc_num = d.doc_num inner join document b on b.doc_num = d.doc_num  where a.doc_type = 'BLCO' and b.doc_type = 'FACA'

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: What database do you use? Oracle? MySQL ? Something else ? That info is very useful and with that info it will be more easy for others to help you.

Comment: What's the criteria for linking the 1000 and 2000 prices to the records you've selected in your result?  Just how do you get 2000 tied to BLCO190123001 Article2  I don't see anyway to tie it to the 2000 article2...

Comment: ARTICLE2 in BLCO190123001 is the same ARTICLE2 in ACHAT190122001 same art_code but with updated price.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
DECLARE @document table (
    DOC_NUM VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,DOC_TYPE VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,DOC_DATE VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @document VALUES
    ('ACHAT190122001', 'FACA', '22/01/2019')
    , ('ACHAT190222001', 'FACA', '22/02/2019')
    , ('ACHAT190322001', 'FACA', '22/03/2019')
    , ('BLCO190122001', 'BLCO', '22/01/2019')
    , ('BLCO190123001', 'BLCO', '23/01/2019')
    , ('BLCM190122001', 'BLCM', '22/01/2019')

DECLARE @documentd TABLE (
    DOC_NUM VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,ART_CODE VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,ART_PRIX SMALLMONEY
)

INSERT INTO @documentd VALUES
    ('ACHAT190122001', 'ARTICLE1', 1000)
    ,('ACHAT190122001', 'ARTICLE2', 2000)
    ,('BLCO190122001', 'ARTICLE1',  900)
    ,('BLCO190123001', 'ARTICLE2',  800)

SELECT d1.DOC_NUM, dd1.ART_CODE, dd2.ART_PRIX, d2.DOC_DATE from @document d1 
INNER JOIN @documentd dd1 ON dd1.DOC_NUM = d1.DOC_NUM
INNER JOIN @documentd dd2 ON dd2.ART_CODE = dd1.ART_CODE
INNER JOIN @document d2 ON d2.DOC_NUM = dd2.DOC_NUM AND d2.DOC_TYPE <> d1.DOC_TYPE
WHERE d1.DOC_TYPE = 'BLCO'
```

This returns:

```
DOC_NUM         ART_CODE    ART_PRIX    DOC_DATE
BLCO190122001   ARTICLE1    1000.00     22/01/2019
BLCO190122001   ARTICLE2    2000.00     22/01/2019
```

From your example results, I assumed you wanted only the BLCO documents and not the BLCM. If you want both, just change the last line to be:

```
WHERE d.DOC_TYPE LIKE 'BLC%' AND d2.DOC_TYPE = 'FACA'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this query don't show any anything when the two condition exist : WHERE d.DOC_TYPE = 'BLCO' AND d2.DOC_TYPE = 'FACA'

Comment: Please I need your help I try everything I know UNION left join views but no result

Comment: Sorry, Mohamed, I'm not sure what the problem could be. I edited my answer to include creation of the sample data you provided in the question. This query returns the two rows you were looking for. Are there differences between your real data and what is in the example?

Comment: One thing to check: make sure the zeros and "O"s match between your real data and what is in the question.

Comment: I changed this to use the joining method proposed by Abra, but in a single query without creating views.

Comment: it is possible to send screenshot for my tables and the result of the query  @Onkel-j

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you want to join all the `FACA` type documents with all the `BLC?` documents on the `ART_CODE` column.

I'm certain it can be done with a single SQL query, but for me it's easier to do it as follows.

1. Create a view for all the `FACA` type documents...

```
create view FACAS as
select DOCUMENTD.DOC_NUM, DOCUMENTD.ART_CODE, DOCUMENTD.ART_PRIX, DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE
from DOCUMENTD join DOCUMENT on DOCUMENTD.DOC_NUM = DOCUMENT.DOC_NUM
where DOCUMENT.DOC_TYPE = 'FACA'
```

2. Create another view for all the `BLC?` type documents...

```
create view BLC_S as
select DOCUMENTD.DOC_NUM, DOCUMENTD.ART_CODE, DOCUMENTD.ART_PRIX, DOCUMENT.DOC_DATE
from DOCUMENTD join DOCUMENT on DOCUMENTD.DOC_NUM = DOCUMENT.DOC_NUM
where DOCUMENT.DOC_TYPE like 'BLC%'
```

Now query both views, joining on the `ART_CODE` column...

```
select BLC_S.DOC_NUM, BLC_S.ART_CODE, FACAS.ART_PRIX, BLC_S.DOC_DATE
from FACAS join BLC_S on FACAS.ART_CODE = BLC_S.ART_CODE
```

Comment: Do you mean the query is displaying the wrong `ART_PRIX` value? I did base my answer on the sample data you provided which shows that there is one `FACA` document and one `BLC?` document for each `ART_CODE`.

Comment: the art_code exist in many different FACA and BLC for clearing the FACA is the invoice how contains the last updated price of article and the BLC is like order with non updating price I need to collect information of BLC between two date with the last updated price existe in  the FACA.